# Why is my apache running in 8080 started by root?

Tags: apache-httpd, uid

I am running Apache in 8080 port. After starting the httpd, I noticed that the parent process is owned by root.

```
[root@a ~]# ps -ef | grep httpd
root     13480     1  0 08:07 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   13505 13480  0 08:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   13506 13480  0 08:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   13507 13480  0 08:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   13508 13480  0 08:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   13509 13480  0 08:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   13510 13480  0 08:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   13511 13480  0 08:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   13512 13480  0 08:11 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
[root@a ~]#
```

I saw below this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134301/why-does-nginx-starts-process-as-root), but it says that by default, for the ports below 1024, root will start process.

If the apache works like this by default, where can I change this?

Thank you.

Comment: start apache with apache user not root.

Comment: Saying root is normally able to open ports < 1014 is different than saying root is starting the process; you may call it with the user apache, you would have to edit the init file. However you may well break it, I suspect. The security mechanism of the privilege separation between the user root and apache exists for a reason.

Comment: Alright. I switched to another user and updated the permissions for `/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid` and `/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid`. Now it is starting with another user. I want to start httpd as root and have apache or another user as process owners. Is that possible?

Comment: Maybe you tell us what you _actually_ want. Why does the httpd launcher process running as root bother you?

Comment: I am just trying to learn things. Just want to know from where exactly the launcher process getting `root` as owner. Is it because `root` starting it?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/03/apache-hardening/

> After this, if you restart apache, and do ps -ef, you’ll see that the apache is running as “apache” (Except the 1st httpd process, which will always run as root).

https://serverfault.com/questions/439307/apache-running-as-root-instead-of-user-specified-in-httpd-conf